# Why I get a cannot cast object 'null' error, when testing my controller?

Tags: grails, spock

I have a controller like this :

```
 def unCompletedTasks() { 
      def user = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id) 
      def choice = params.managersProject 
      params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10,100) 
      def search = Tasks.createCriteria().list(max: params.max as Integer, offset: params.offset as Integer, order: params.order as String, sort : params.sort) { 
            and { 
                  project { 
                     like('name',"${choice}") 
                  } 
                  eq('completed',false) 
                  lt('endDate',new Date().clearTime()) 
            } 
      } 

      [tasksInstanceList : search, tasksInstanceTotal: search.getTotalCount() ] 
    }
```

I want to test this. I wrote a test specification in Spock like this:

```
    def 'user should be displayed unCompletedTasks' () { 

            setup: "set the required objects" 
            def tasksController = new TasksController() 
            tasksController.springSecurityService = [principal: [id:tasksInstance.id]] 
            tasksController.params.managersProject = "testing" 
           //other codings goes here 

            when: 
            def model = tasksController.unCompletedTasks() 

            then: 
            model.tasksInstanceTotal == 1 

            where: 
            //required fields 
    }
```

When I run, I get a error like this :

```
 user should be displayed unCompletedTasks(mnm.schedule.TasksSpec) 
|  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject' to class 'java.lang.Integer' 
        at mnm.schedule.TasksController.unCompletedTasks(TasksController.groovy:39) 
        at mnm.schedule.TasksSpec.user should be displayed unCompletedTasks(TasksSpec.groovy:59)
```

I don't know where I went wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What line of code is `TasksController.groovy:39` on? (since we don't have line numbers here).

Comment: @JarredOlson: that is the start of the criteria query: `def search = Tasks.createCriteria().list . . . . //other code`.

Comment: I'm not sure why any of those `as Integer` would be throwing that error.  I would try taking them out one at a time and see which one(s) are throwing the error.  One thing to keep in mind is that through a web interface all params will be Strings (empty if they don't have a value).  So to emulate that you should be setting all non-value params as empty strings.  For example on the line `params.max ? params.int('max')` params.max would be an empty string in production code but it's being set as null from your test.  It doesn't appear to be the source of you problem, but could save you later.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the same problem as discussed in [Problems casting a null object with Spock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756297/problems-casting-a-null-object-with-spock). The solution is to upgrade to Grails 2.0.2.