# Problems casting a null object with Spock

Tags: exception, grails, groovy, casting, spock

I have a Spock test that fails over two Mac OS X Lion machines, but works over other Linux machines and the [Spock Web Console](http://meetspock.appspot.com/).

I found another related question: [Why I get a cannot cast object 'null' error, when testing my controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10040162/462015)

I'm using Grails 2.0.0 and Spock 0.6. Any suggestions? Seems to be a bug

```
def "casting null object"() {
    expect:
    null as BigDecimal == null
}

| Failure:  casting null object(com.arturoherrero.MySpec)
|  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject' to class 'java.math.BigDecimal'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've hit [this bug with Grails 2.0.0](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8800)

That says it was fixed for Grails 2.0.2, so maybe an upgrade on one of your machines to check is in order?

Fingers crossed!